# Application of monotone class theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

currently I am reviewing the montone class theorem and I believe the following exercise is true:

**Exercise**: Using a monotone class theorem argument prove the following: Let $X,Y$ be two (real) random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb P)$ and suppose that
$$
\mathbb E[g(X) Y] = \mathbb E[g(X)] \mathbb E[Y] \quad \forall g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded, continuous and Borel},
$$
holds true (note: Here one only demands that $g$ is continuous and not simply bounded). Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one can prove it the following way:

**Solution**: It is a well-known fact in probability theory that
$$
\mathbb E[g(X) Y] = \mathbb E[g(X)] \mathbb E[Y] \quad \forall g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded and Borel}, 
$$
implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So having the above result for continuous maps, bounded maps that are Borel we need to lift this result to all bounded maps that are Borel and this is exactly where monotone class theorem comes into play. Hence choose the following:

1. We choose the real vector space of functions given by $\mathcal{H} = $ { $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \mid g \text{ is bounded, borel and } \mathbb E[g(X) Y] = E[g(X)] E[Y] \quad \forall Y \in \mathcal{A}$}. This is clearly contining the constant function and is closed under bounded monotone convergence.
2. We choose as an auxiliary set $\mathcal{M} = $ { $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \mid g \text{is bounded, borel and satisfies the equation above} $}, which is clearly contained in $\mathcal{H}$ and generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$. Also $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under multiplication.
3. Applying montone class theorem yields that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded Borel functions, hence one has that for all random variables $Y$ that are $\mathcal{A}$ measurable that
   $$
   E[g(X) Y] = E[g(X)] E[Y] \quad \forall g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded, Borel},
   $$
   holds true and this finishes the proof.

**Question**: What is the smallest family of functions that one can extend by montone class theorem to test on regarding independence under factorizing expected value?.